# Redirect subdomain to index .php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect my subdomain to its index file and main domain to its own index file.

Example

for www.example.com -> index.html

subdomain.example.com - >index.php

I have following rule for the main domain

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
```

**www.example.com root folder is public/**

while

**subdomain.example.com root folder is  public/folder/**

Main domain redirection is working. But how to redirect subdomain.example.com to its index.php ie to **public/folder/index.php** ? Should there be seperate .htaccess file or common file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use in public/ .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ folder%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

And in folder/ .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```